# How to create a react website that displays formatted user generated text?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say you want to display writing on your website. Maybe it's a blog or a website like a medium or even Stackoverflow. You want users to be able to submit their writing. Format the text (make certain parts bold or italic), insert pictures between texts, and so on.

How would you go about doing this? I think I could figure out hacky ways to do it, but what is the best practice for making that sort of website?

Comment: Are you referring to having a WYSIWYG component?

Comment: Exactly. I had no idea there was a term for it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a headless CMS, wysiwyg editor, markdown editor, ... you'll most probably get HTML back as a `string`, which you'll need to output.

As you might have noticed, hence you question, you can't just output `<div>{html}</div>` in your React component. This is because React [escapes certain characters to prevent XSS](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#jsx-prevents-injection-attacks).

In order to display user submitted HTML, you can use https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml. The reason for the weird name is that you will allow users to output unsafe HTML which might execute JavaScript or network requests on your website. This can have [huge security consequences](https://brightsec.com/blog/xss/). You'll have to run the HTML through a sanitizer, which will strip any HTML attributes that can be used to execute JavaScript and escape characters like React does. Don't attempt to do this yourself, people constantly find new ways to bypass these sanitizers.

Sanitizers you can use:

- https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify
- https://github.com/apostrophecms/sanitize-html

Email applications will sometimes use a sandboxed iframe to display raw HTML from emails but for content that's not really an option (SEO).